# Highlight text on Lyx documents

Tags: highlight, lyx, mathtype

I am using Lyx for my homework (text+math) for a while now, but there are a few features I couldn't find and it is hard for me to believe they don't exist (even with some workaround).

#### Is there an option to highlight text on LYX?

example for how I'd like it to appear on my PDF product:
[an example for PDF with highlighted text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH4J8.png)

I couldn't find it on the interface or settings.
I googled it, asked my T.As, posted a question on several Lyx related facebook communities - but couldn't find any solution.
On the other hand, no one told me "I have checked it and it's not possible" - so I keep looking.‍♂️

Some add-on? Packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with "Soul" module. Here are the steps:

1. Download the [module](https://wiki.lyx.org/uploads/Modules/soul.module).
2. Put the module in the "layouts" directory inside your user directory. You can find your user directory by going to Help > About.
3. In LyX, do Tools > Reconfigure.
4. Restart LyX.
5. Open a document in LyX and go to Document Settings > Modules. After steps (3) and (4) you should now see "Soul Text Markup" as a module. Click "Add" and then "OK". Here is a screenshot (before clicking "Add"):

[image]

6. After (5), you can now select text in your document and go to Edit > Text Style > highlight.

More information is on the [module wiki page](https://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/Modules). I have never heard of Facebook LyX communites. I suggest instead to join our lyx-users mailing list. There are a lot of knowledgeable and friendly LyX users helping each other out.

Comment: Great! I hope to see you around on the lyx-users mailing list :)